# Dropdown as 12Hours format and Save as 24 hours Format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, timepicker

I'm having problem on how to save the value of the Time Picker of Kendo to 24 Hours Format , 
My Dropdown shows "HH:mm tt" format but i want to convert it to "HH:mm:ss" , I use Time Span for my drowdown list

Sample Codes

```
//having error because Endtime's value is "HH:mm tt"  
clientShift.EndTime = TimeSpan.Parse(endTime.Trim());

clientShift.EndTime = new DateTime(endTime).ToString("HH:mm");

clientShift.EndTime =TimeSpan.ParseExact(endTime,"hh\\:mm\\:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: what line throws an error?

Comment: What is exactly your problem ? Do you want to **show** at the user a 24h formatted time or do you want to **save** that time after the user selected it in a 24h formatted time ?

Comment: i want to show 12h format at timepicker then save it to 24hour format @Atlasmaybe

Comment: Please give us more information about the type of `endTime` and `clientShift.EndTime`. After that, I think I can give you an answer.